# Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0 Windows 10 Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, gtk3, clion

i wrote this program in C on my win10 pc using Clion 2019.2.4.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWindow *window;

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_widget_show(window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

This is my CmakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(gtk_test C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

# Use the package PkgConfig to detect GTK+ headers/library files
FIND_PACKAGE(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GTK REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)

# Setup CMake to use GTK+, tell the compiler where to look for headers
# and to the linker where to look for libraries
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${GTK_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${GTK_LIBRARY_DIRS})

# Add other flags to the compiler
ADD_DEFINITIONS(${GTK_CFLAGS_OTHER} )

# Add an executable compiled from hello.c
add_executable(gtk_test main.c)

# Link the target to the GTK+ libraries
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(gtk_test ${GTK_LIBRARIES})
```

But when i try to run it...:

```
Hello, World!
Unable to init server: Could not connect to 127.0.0.1: Connection refused

(gtk_test:2342): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQf7H.jpg

I am using Cygwin: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN8z2.jpg

Comment: Do you really have to use Cygwin? If you use Cygwin you will also need a X11 server implementation for Windows, like Cygwin/X or Xming. Anyway, Gtk supports Windows natively and by running natively you may have a much better experience. Try [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/), follow the steps outlined here: https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php

Answer (score 0):

Your test program is in the same condition mentioned at
https://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html#q-remote-clients-cant-connect

> The X server now uses -nolisten tcp by default, which increases the
>   security of the X server by not opening a TCP/IP socket.
>
> Use the -listen tcp option to allow the X server to open a TCP/IP
>   socket as well, e.g. startxwin -- -listen tcp